# Django template csv writer inserts blank lines

Tags: django, python-2.7, csv

I am printing some csv file by writing into `header_template.csv`:

```
{% load devicetags %}
{% get_headers device_list %}
```

Now, Django adds a blank line before and after the output of `get_headers`, which is a comma separated string.  The output looks like this:

```
*blank line*
a,b,c
*blank line*
```

I know that this behaviour often occurs with python, and that normally, I would just have to open the file with `'wb'`, but I am not directly opening the file here and thus cannot pass a flag. Can I somehow tell Django to use `'wb'` instead of `'w'`?

Comment: What happens if you change the two lines to a single one: `{% load devicetags %}{% get_headers device_list %}`?

Comment: thank you, I didn't think that would make a difference!

Comment: You shouldn't really use templates to generate CSVs. Use the csv module to generate it directly in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering CSV through a template is not the ideal way to do it - aside from the new line issue you have already discovered, you can easily run into other issues with content not being quoted correctly.

You should consider using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library to generate the CSV in python. This will handle properly quoting and escaping values before writing them.

There is a section in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-csv/#outputting-csv-with-django) on outputting CSV with Django.